# Serial port access application using jSerialComm library is not getting LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE events

Tags: java, events, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a BLE module over a serial port connection.  The hardware is implemented by a USB-to-Serial device which makes it difficult to probe the interface pins.

The problem is that while I can "see" the writes to the BLE device in a software package that displays the USB traffic I do not see any responses from the BLE device.  I can send and receive data to the BLE device using teraTerm.

(Note:  I suspect the USB sniffer program will only "see" data from the BLE or loop-back device if my Java application calls a read function.)

I switched the serial port from the BLE device to a generic USB-to-Serial device with transmit wired to receive and RTS wired to CTS.  Any data sent to the port should be echoed back.  It works with a serial port emulator (teraTerm) so I know the hardware is ok but my Java application does not respond.

I set breakpoints in the getListeningEvents() and serialEvent() methods but they do not get called.  It looks like I have not setup the code properly to get events.  Unfortunately the examples for the jSerialComm library are all code snippets and do not include a full functional program so I suspect some detail about the overall application structure might be my problem.

The code was originally separated between GUI-related code and serial port related code but I had problems with static and non-static objects.  I have 30+ years of C experience and about 6 weeks of Java use.  Putting it all in one class was the sledgehammer approach but I couldn't find a better solution.  Although just because it compiles doesn't mean it's right...

mainScreen.java is:

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author SGrunza
 */
public class mainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

   static SerialPort portNINA;
   static String portNINAstr;

   public void msSleep(int msToSleep)
   {
      try
         {
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(msToSleep);
         }
      catch (InterruptedException ex)
         {
         System.out.println(ex);
         }
   }

   public String pickPort(JFrame topFrame)
   {

      String retVal;

      SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

      // Create array of descriptive port names
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; i++)
         {
         names.add(ports[i].getDescriptivePortName());
         }

      // Turn ArrayList into String array
      String nameString[] = new String[names.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
         {
         nameString[i] = names.get(i);
         }

      // Choose the port
      retVal = ListDialog.showDialog(
              topFrame,
              topFrame,
              "Choose the serial port used by the NINA module",
              "Configure Serial Port",
              nameString,
              null,
              null);

      //System.out.println( retVal );
      portNINAstr = retVal;
      portNINA = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
         {
         if (nameString[i].equals(portNINAstr))
            {
            // Found it
            portNINA = ports[i];
            }
         }

      return retVal;
   }

   public void openNINAport() 
   {
      portNINA.openPort();

      portNINA.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener()
      {
         @Override
         public int getListeningEvents()
         {
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
         }

         @Override
         public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event
         )
         {
            if (event.getEventType() == SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE)
               {
               while (portNINA.bytesAvailable() > 0)
                  {
                  byte[] newData = new byte[portNINA.bytesAvailable()];
                  int numRead = portNINA.readBytes(newData, newData.length);
                  setFromLog(newData, numRead);
                  }
               }
         }

      });

   }

   public void setFromLog(byte[] data, int len)
   {
      String text = new String(data);

      fromNINAlog.append(text + "\r\n");
      fromNINAlog.update(fromNINAlog.getGraphics());
   }

   public void setToLog(byte[] data, int len)
   {
      String text = new String(data);

      toNINAlog.append(text + "\r\n");
      toNINAlog.update(toNINAlog.getGraphics());
   }

   public void setFromLog(String text)
   {
      fromNINAlog.append(text + "\r\n");
      fromNINAlog.update(fromNINAlog.getGraphics());
   }

   public void setToLog(String text)
   {
      toNINAlog.append(text + "\r\n");
      toNINAlog.update(toNINAlog.getGraphics());
   }

   public void healthCheck()
   {
      Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);

      String timeString = new String();

      timeString = timeString.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
      clockField.setText(timeString);
      //System.out.println( timeString );

      if (portNINA != null)
         {
         if (portNINA.isOpen())
            {
            commStatusTextField.setText(portNINA.getSystemPortName() + " open");

            if (portNINA.bytesAvailable() > 0)
               {
               System.out.println("Data available on com port");
               }

            }
         else
            {
            commStatusTextField.setText(portNINA.getSystemPortName() + " not open");
            }
         }
      else
         {
         commStatusTextField.setText("Not open");
         }

   } // end of healthCheck()

   /**
    * Creates new form mainScreen
    */
   public mainScreen()
   {
      Timer healthTimer = new Timer();

      initComponents();

      fromNINAlog.setLineWrap(true);
      fromNINAlog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
      toNINAlog.setLineWrap(true);
      toNINAlog.setWrapStyleWord(true);

      healthTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            //System.out.println( "healthTask " + new Date() +
            //        "Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
            healthCheck();
         }
      },
              0, // delay until first run
              1000); // delay for each subsequent run

      clockField.setToolTipText("If the clock is updating, the code is running");
      clockField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

      // Picking COM port each time is annoying
      String retVal;

      SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

      // Create array of descriptive port names
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; i++)
         {
         names.add(ports[i].getDescriptivePortName());
         }

      // Turn ArrayList into String array
      String nameString[] = new String[names.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
         {
         nameString[i] = names.get(i);
         }

      // Should be from a config file
      portNINAstr = "USB Serial Port (COM19)";
      portNINA = null;

      for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
         {
         if (nameString[i].equals(portNINAstr))
            {
            // Found it
            portNINA = ports[i];
            }
         }

      // Handle case where default didn't work
      if (portNINA == null)
         {
         portNINAstr = null;
         }
   }

   /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize
    * the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this
    * method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents()
   {

      helpAboutDialog = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();
      jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
      resetButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      factoryResetButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      connectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      clockField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      disconnectButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      commStatusTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
      configureNINAbutton = new javax.swing.JButton();
      jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
      jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      toNINAlog = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
      jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      fromNINAlog = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
      FileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
      QuitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
      EditMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
      ConfigMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
      configSerialPort = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
      HelpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
      AboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Bogie IQ Emulator");

      jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

      resetButton.setText("Reset");

      factoryResetButton.setText("Factory Reset");
      factoryResetButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            factoryResetButtonActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      connectButton.setText("Connect");
      connectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            connectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      disconnectButton.setText("Disconnect");
      disconnectButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            disconnectButtonActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      jLabel1.setText("Comm Status:");

      commStatusTextField.setToolTipText("Select Comm port in Config menu");

      configureNINAbutton.setText("Configure NINA");
      configureNINAbutton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            configureNINAbuttonActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
      jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
      jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                     .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(resetButton)
                        .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                        .addComponent(configureNINAbutton))
                     .addComponent(disconnectButton))
                  .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                  .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                     .addComponent(factoryResetButton)
                     .addComponent(clockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
               .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                  .addComponent(connectButton)
                  .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                  .addComponent(jLabel1)
                  .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                  .addComponent(commStatusTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                  .addGap(0, 189, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
      );

      jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {clockField, connectButton, disconnectButton, factoryResetButton, resetButton});

      jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
         jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(resetButton)
               .addComponent(clockField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
               .addComponent(configureNINAbutton))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
               .addComponent(connectButton)
               .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                  .addComponent(jLabel1)
                  .addComponent(commStatusTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(disconnectButton)
               .addComponent(factoryResetButton))
            .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );

      jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("To NINA"));

      toNINAlog.setColumns(20);
      toNINAlog.setRows(5);
      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(toNINAlog);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
      jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
      jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
      );
      jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
         jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 165, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      );

      jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("From NINA"));

      fromNINAlog.setColumns(20);
      fromNINAlog.setRows(5);
      jScrollPane2.setViewportView(fromNINAlog);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
      jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
      jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
      );
      jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
         jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 181, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      );

      FileMenu.setText("File");

      QuitMenuItem.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
      QuitMenuItem.setText("Quit");
      QuitMenuItem.setToolTipText("No checks so be careful");
      QuitMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            QuitMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });
      FileMenu.add(QuitMenuItem);

      jMenuBar1.add(FileMenu);

      EditMenu.setText("Edit");
      jMenuBar1.add(EditMenu);

      ConfigMenu.setText("Config");

      configSerialPort.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_P, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
      configSerialPort.setText("Serial Port");
      configSerialPort.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            configSerialPortActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });
      ConfigMenu.add(configSerialPort);

      jMenuBar1.add(ConfigMenu);

      HelpMenu.setText("Help");
      HelpMenu.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            HelpMenuActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });

      AboutMenuItem.setText("About");
      AboutMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
      {
         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
         {
            AboutMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
         }
      });
      HelpMenu.add(AboutMenuItem);

      jMenuBar1.add(HelpMenu);

      setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
               .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
               .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
      );

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>                        

   private void QuitMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
   {                                                 
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      System.exit(0);
   }                                            

   private void HelpMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
   {                                             
      // TODO add your handling code here:
   }                                        

   private void AboutMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                              
   {                                                  
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      // Trying to launch an About dialog
      String versionString;
      try
         {
         versionString = "Compiled on " + programBuildTime.getLastModifiedDate();
         }
      catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex)
         {
         versionString = "Unknown";
         }

      System.out.println("Version Info is: " + versionString);

      helpAboutDialog.showMessageDialog(jPanel1,
              versionString, // Message info
              "Version Info",
              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }                                             

   private void configSerialPortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                 
   {                                                     
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);

      pickPort(topFrame);
   }                                                

   private void factoryResetButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                   
   {                                                       
      // TODO add your handling code here:
   }                                                  

   private void connectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                              
   {                                                  
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      if (portNINAstr != null)
         {
         // Try to open the serial port
         fromNINAlog.append("Connecting to " + portNINAstr + "\r\n");
         toNINAlog.append("Connecting to " + portNINAstr + "\r\n");

         portNINA.openPort();

         portNINA.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 2000, 2000);
         portNINA.setComPortParameters(115200, 8, SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
         portNINA.setFlowControl(SerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_ENABLED | SerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_CTS_ENABLED);
         //portNINA.setFlowControl(SerialPort.FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLED);
         portNINA.setDTR();
         portNINA.setRTS();

         }
      else
         {
         javax.swing.JOptionPane errDialog = new javax.swing.JOptionPane();
         errDialog.showMessageDialog(errDialog,
                 "No serial port selected", // Message info
                 "Serial Port Error",
                 helpAboutDialog.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
   }                                             

   private void disconnectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                 
   {                                                     
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      if (portNINAstr != null)
         {
         if (portNINA.isOpen())
            {
            // Turn off the module
            portNINA.clearDTR();
            portNINA.closePort();
            }
         }
   }                                                

   private void configureNINAbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                    
   {                                                        
      // TODO add your handling code here:
      if (portNINAstr != null)
         {
         if (portNINA.isOpen())
            {
            String cfgString;
            byte[] cfg;

            // Make sure NINA is in control/AT mode
            portNINA.clearDTR();
            msSleep(500);
            portNINA.setDTR();

            // Configure device name.  Should be looked up from BIQ
            // serial number
            //cfgString = "AT+UBTLN=\"BIQ_emu-001930" + clockField.getText() + "\"";
            cfgString = "AT+UBTLN=\"BIQ_" + clockField.getText() + "\"";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            // Set GAP connectable mode
            cfgString = "AT+UBTCM=2";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            // Set GAP general discoverable mode
            cfgString = "AT+UBTDM=3";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            // Set GAP pairing mode
            cfgString = "AT+UBTPM=2";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            // Set Bluetooth low energy Peripheral
            cfgString = "AT+UBTLE=2";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            // Switch to extended data mode
            cfgString = "ATO2";
            cfg = cfgString.getBytes();
            portNINA.writeBytes(cfg, cfg.length);
            setToLog(cfgString);
            msSleep(2000);

            }
         }
   }                                                   

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
      //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
      /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
       */
      try
         {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
            {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
               {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
               }
            }
         }
      catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
         {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      catch (InstantiationException ex)
         {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
         {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
         {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainScreen.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      //</editor-fold>

      /* Create and display the form */
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         public void run()
         {
            new mainScreen().setVisible(true);

         }
      });
   }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   public javax.swing.JMenuItem AboutMenuItem;
   public javax.swing.JMenu ConfigMenu;
   public javax.swing.JMenu EditMenu;
   public javax.swing.JMenu FileMenu;
   public javax.swing.JMenu HelpMenu;
   public javax.swing.JMenuItem QuitMenuItem;
   public javax.swing.JTextField clockField;
   public javax.swing.JTextField commStatusTextField;
   public javax.swing.JMenuItem configSerialPort;
   public javax.swing.JButton configureNINAbutton;
   public javax.swing.JButton connectButton;
   public javax.swing.JButton disconnectButton;
   public javax.swing.JButton factoryResetButton;
   public javax.swing.JTextArea fromNINAlog;
   public javax.swing.JOptionPane helpAboutDialog;
   public javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
   public javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
   public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
   public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
   public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
   public javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
   public javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
   public javax.swing.JButton resetButton;
   public javax.swing.JTextArea toNINAlog;
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

If you actual build and run this code, you'll need to select a serial port with a loop-back (RX to TX, CTS to RTS) to get it to work.  If you disable flow control then you only need the TX to RX connection.

Select the Config menu to pick a serial port, then select Connect to open the serial port.  Then select "Configure NINA" to send a bunch of text to the loop-back connection.  You should see the text going to the NINA module in the "To NINA" window and the same text in the "From NINA" module.

There is a healthCheck method that updates the clock in the upper right hand side of the screen.  If the jSerialComm bytesAvailble() method returns a non-zero value, then the library has seen that there is data to be read but the event to read it wasn't trigger.

There may be a lot wrong with this code.  I'm willing to learn how to fix it but the key problem is the lack of a LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE event.

My environment is NetBeans 8.2 with Java 8 on Win10 64-bit.